# Change :before value via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-class

I want to change  para-top **:before** left value via JQuery.

```
.para-top:before {
    left: 5%;
}
```

Expected Result:

```
.para-top:before {
    left: 284px;
}
```

.attr not working for  CSS Left.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: $(this).attr('data-content','bar');

.attr is not working for a CSS change, It only work for DATA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manipulate `:before`, because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you can add a new class with a new `:before specified`.

```
$('.para-top').toggleClass('changed');
```

Hope this helps. 
Credits to: **@Blazemonger**

Comment: Its helped. Thanks a lot.